# ElementTree, fromstring() error - AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'

Tags: python, xml

I was using parse function to modify a xml and it worked but I tried to use .fromstring and it showed an error

> AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'

here is the part of code.

```
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'
```

Comment: That's an error message, not code.

Comment: `Element` object has no `getroot()` method, whereas `ElementTree` has. Post the code raising the error.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the fromstring method returns the root object already. SO whatever your var that stores the information form the "fromstring()" method is, that var is the root.